# selecting character from a record in RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby, character

i tried to selecting a record on database based on character on it

here's my method in my model (article.rb)

```
def self.show_high_content
self.where("description.characters > 100")
end
```

i want to select the record that JUST has a 100 more character on description field on it
so the description with least than 100 character will not be displayed.

it appear an error like this

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'description.characters' in 'where clause': SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles`  WHERE (description.characters > 100)
```

thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using MySQL's `CHAR_LENGTH` function:

```
def self.show_high_content
  where("CHAR_LENGTH(description) > ?", 100)
end
```

See documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length).